# How to add foreach inside switch php

Tags: php, switch-statement

anyone know how to this?

```
switch ($page) {
  foreach ($getcustpage as $k => $v) {
   case $v:
    print 'Variable $v tripped switch: '.$k.'<br>'.$v;
   break;
  }
   case "result":
    //result
   break;
   default:
    //default 
   break;
}
```

I want to create a custom page from my settings. So the page will be available to access.
anyone can help me?

Comment: use in_array($page, $getcustpage) && $page !== 'result', elseif $page === 'result' else default vs trying to dynamically create a switch

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution.

First i create normal switch like this

```
switch ($page) {
   case "result":
    //result
   break;
   default:
    //default 
   break;
}
```

Then i need to add a logic in default switch

```
if (in_array($page, $getcustpage)) {
  foreach ($getcustpage as $k => $v) {
    print 'Variable $v tripped switch: '.$k.'<br>'.$v;
  }
}else{
   print $page;
}
```

Thanks for help.

Answer (score 0):

I think you should break out your for loop outside of the switch. Now it is incorrect syntax.
Try this:

```
foreach ($getcustpage as $k => $v) {
     switch ($k) {
   case $v:
    print 'Variable $v tripped switch: '.$k.'<br>'.$v;
   break;
   case "result":
    //result
   break;
   default:
    //default 
   break;
    }
}
```